# json object has string over it, how to remove?

Tags: javascript

I'm returning a response from my server like this,

```
{
exercise_activity_time: "["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"]"
}
```

The array has a string around it - i'm trying to remove that so i can access the array itself.

i.e.,

```
  console.log("first time", Settings.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')[0]);
```

To access the first entry.

This is not working! Any other ideas on how to access the data?

Thanks

Comment: better fix this from server so that it return the actual array as value

Comment: It's double encoding. `JSON.parse(Settings.exercise_activity_time)`

Comment: I agree but at the moment IMO just want to have it working client side

Comment: @LeCoda Try `eval` I think that is exactly what you want

Comment: Dont use `eval` since it will run anything that is passed to it it can run malisous code easily: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using JSON.parse(exercise_activity_time)?

Answer (score 0):

If your response is an object like

```
obj = {exercise_activity_time: '["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"]'};
```

you can do

```
obj.exercise_activity_time = JSON.parse(obj.exercise_activity_time);
```

to parse it back to a real array.

However, it'd be better to fix the backend to return that array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON.parse` in combination with `Array.from` in this way:

```js
console.log("first time", Array.from(JSON.parse("[\"09:00 AM\",\"12:00 PM\",\"03:00 PM\"]"))[0]);
```